# How to change font size in an Amplify list component?

Tags: css, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I'm using Figma-built components in Amplify.  The components here are card collections. What I want to do is change the font size for a particular field in one collection of cards.  Here is what a close inspection of the page looks like (see below).
The highlighted section is the area I want to change.

[image]

I tried this construct in my css file (below), but it has no effect.

```css
.styled-text .amplify-flex .amplify-collection .amplify-collection-items .amplify-text {
    font-size: 44px;
}
```

The way I am using `.styled-text` is as follows (below).

```html
            <KatsuKappoCardioCardCollection className="styled-text"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're auto-generating the code with Amplify Studio, the best approach is most likely to override Amplify styles as documented here with the `overrides` prop:

https://amplify.aws/learn/courses/Fullstack-for-Frontend-Developers-e7319/lessons/9

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't have any effect.  I also tried changing the HTML entry to 
```
<KatsuKappoCardioCardCollection  className="styled-text amplify-text"/>
```
and that didn't change anything either.

Comment: Any chance you could make a CodeSandbox of the above? Would be helpful to debug further

Comment: Also, are you sure your style sheet is being imported and applied?

Comment: Yes, my stylesheet is being imported and applied because I can see the instant change to the element:
`<div class="amplify-flex amplify-collection styled-text amplify-text">`

Comment: I'll look into CodeSandbox.  Haven't used that before.

Comment: CodeSandbox doesn't like all the Amplify-specific style items. :(

Comment: Ah, I see! You could also try codepen (alternative to CodeSandbox) and double check that other styles in the same style sheet are getting imported and applied.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253832/discussion-between-tennis-smith-and-ionosphere).